# Is vaping e-liquids halal?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sharia, halal-certification, smoking

I quit smoking and am willing to vape 0 nocotine e-liquids, but I read a lot about e-liquids that they contain VG and PG in their ingredients. Can anyone confirm if PG is fine and not haram?

Answer (score 1):

Aslamu Walaykum

Brother, do not use these cigarettes, all of them are haram. The PG ingredient is haram, and whatever it is even liquid. They are haram. It is better if you do not use these nicotine mysterious cigarettes which are harmful to your health and to your iman as well.